# How to bind the enter/return key to user-defined function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing an application that runs on one page, and does not reload. I have a form with only an input type text, no submit button. I included the onchange event, after filling the textbox with data, I want to execute the function bound to the onchange event when I press enter, but the form is rather submitted and [it attempts to load a new page]. Please what do I do? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hook the `keypress` event on the text box and call your handler, and cancel the event to prevent the form submission:

```
$("selector_for_your_text_box").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        // call your `change` logic here

        // Cancel the event
        return false;
    }
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ewalo5)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(function() {
   $('#yourInput').keypress(function(event) {
      var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
      if (key == 13) {
         event.preventDefault();
         // call your function here
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuo can bind to the `keypress` event on the input:

```
$('#inputfieldid').keypress(function() {
  alert('Handler for .keypress() called.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the demo link   http://jsfiddle.net/HDkJW/